# Inexpensive Android Device for Web Dev

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

I am looking for an inexpensive Android device almost entirely to use as a test bed for jQuery Mobile web based development. I only require WiFi. Similar question to [Android Development Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803466/) but I don't need the native Android app capability, side loading etc.

More modern tablets are slightly interesting but I don't think that gives me the most realistic end-use case and the WAF isn't exactly high. Suggestions? What do people think of somehting like a [Samsung GT-S5630L Galaxy Y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00766BFHS)? Or is a [Samsung Galaxy 4.0 Android MP3 Player](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005P1VNDW) a better option?

How different is the browser as you move from Gingerbread to Honeycomb or ICS?

I realize this question isn't ideal for SO as it is not directly related to programming but I can't seem to find the answer elseware and am looking for some help with my programming related work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a copy paste from one of my apps according to usage

The higher the "score" the better the device is good for testing, since it's more popular.

Samsung Galaxy Y
2,406 8.64 %

Samsung Galaxy S2
2,330 8.37 %

Samsung Galaxy Tab
1,167 4.19 %

Samsung Galaxy Note
926 3.33 %

Toshiba AT100
840 3.02 %

Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P7510)
825 2.96 %

Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 (GT-P7500)
710 2.55 %

Samsung Galaxy Ace
710 2.55 %

HTC Desire HD
678 2.44 %
Others
17,240 61.94 %

Comment: also, the browser it's the same.... all support html5 so your apps should look ~99% on all.